# What does it mean for a value to be minimised?

Tags: optimization

I am trying to solve this [problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=44), but I do not understand what is meant bythe following expression being minimised

$$ D = P_{k} + P_{j} $$

Comment: Can you type in the whole sentence?

Comment: For each pair $(j,k)$ the expression $|P_k-P_j|$ has some value. Find the pair for which this value is smallest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value is minimised when it becomes as small as it can.

I expect that your $P_k$ and $P_j$ are points. Then $\|P_k-P_j\|$ is the distance between any two points. To minimise $\|P_k-P_j\|$ is to find the two points that are closest to one another out of all the other possible pairs of points.